# I want insert data from a table with random in two column I tried but failed

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two table from table `pay_in_out` I want to insert data in advance salary and selecting random from table but failed any one can tell me please

```
INSERT INTO  ADVANCE_SALARY (EMPLOYEECODE,ADV_DATE)
    VALUES (SELECT EMP_CODE,ATT_DATE
    FROM   PAY_IN_OUT
    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)
WHERE  rownum < 40
AND ATT_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-09-01' AND DATE '2021-03-31'
AND  ((TO_CHAR(ATT_DATE, 'DAY'))) != 'SUNDAY');
```

I tried also like this but failed

```
INSERT INTO  ADVANCE_SALARY (EMPLOYEECODE, ADV_DATE)
    SELECT    
     EMPLOYEECODE,
     ADV_DATE
     FROM 
     (SELECT EMP_CODE,ATT_DATE
    FROM   PAY_IN_OUT
    WHERE ATT_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-09-01' AND DATE '2021-03-31'
AND  ((TO_CHAR(ATT_DATE, 'DAY'))) != 'SUNDAY'
    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)
WHERE  rownum < 40;
```

it says `adb_date` invalid identifier
but select query works fine

```
SELECT EMP_CODE,ATT_DATE
FROM   (
    SELECT EMP_CODE,ATT_DATE
    FROM   PAY_IN_OUT
    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)
WHERE  rownum < 40
AND ATT_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-09-01' AND DATE '2021-03-31'
AND  ((TO_CHAR(ATT_DATE, 'DAY'))) != 'SUNDAY';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are flexible about the 39 rows, you could think of using `SAMPLE`, which is somewhat cleaner and faster:

```
INSERT INTO ADVANCE_SALARY (EMPLOYEECODE, ADV_DATE)
SELECT EMP_CODE, ATT_DATE
  FROM pay_in_out SAMPLE (5)
 WHERE ATT_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-09-01' AND DATE '2021-03-31'
   AND ((TO_CHAR(ATT_DATE, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH'))) != 'SUNDAY';
```

You'll need to adjust the sample size (here 5%) to your data volume.

Answer (score 1):

ok i got this its like this

```
INSERT INTO  ADVANCE_SALARY (EMPLOYEECODE, ADV_DATE)
    SELECT    
     EMP_CODE,
     ATT_DATE
     FROM 
     (SELECT EMP_CODE,ATT_DATE
    FROM   PAY_IN_OUT
    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)
    WHERE ATT_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-09-01' AND DATE '2021-03-31'
    AND  ((TO_CHAR(ATT_DATE, 'DAY'))) != 'SUNDAY'
    AND  rownum < 40;
```